# Is there a way to draw an arow line for subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to draw an arrow line for my 2 subplots out of 3 subplots, previously if there were no subplots, I have successfully drawn an arrow line using:

```
plt.arrow(0.1, 0.16, 0.3, 0.0, head_width=0.005, head_length=0.03, linewidth=0.75, color='black', length_includes_head=True)
```

But for subplots it's not working, could any one kindly comment/suggest. Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Sorry for bothering you all, I used the following lines for doing this, could be useful to someone like me:

```
axs1[0].arrow(7.5, 0.40, 3.25, 0, head_width=0.25, head_length=0.40, linewidth=1.1, color='black', length_includes_head=True)
```